# C# テキストボックスへの表示が遅い解消法について

Tags: c#, file

お世話になります。

C#(.Net4.6.1)で、ファイルのダンプ表示をするコードを書いて勉強中なのですが、正しく
動いてしてるようなのですが、結果の表示で何か処理が重い気がします。

12M(約4000万文字)のテキストファイルをダンプ表示させようとしたのですが、
二時間たっても終わりませんでした。バイトへの解析は早く終わっているのですが、
TextBoxに表示する際にとても時間がかかっているようです。

もっと高速にできる方法がありましたら、ご教授ください。

以下が、そのソースコードです。

```
private void dump(string filename)
{
    this.tsslFileName.Text = Path.GetFileName(filename);

    byte[] btBin = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    this.stValues = BitConverter.ToString(btBin);

   this.areaBinary.Text = "";　　　　//  これはテキストボックス

    string stBuf = stValues;

    int iAddress = 0;
    string stDisp = "";

    //  何行かごとにTextBoxに吐き出す。
    int block = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        if(stBuf.Length < 47)
        {
            stDisp += iAddress.ToString("X8") + " | " + (stBuf + "\r\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            stDisp += iAddress.ToString("X8") + " | " + (stBuf.Substring(0,47) + "\r\n");
            stBuf = stBuf.Substring(48);
        }
        iAddress += 16;

        block++;

        if(block >= 40)
        {
            block = 0;
            this.areaBinary.AppendText(stDisp);
            stDisp = "";
            System.GC.Collect();
        }

        this.Text = "残り　" + stBuf.Length + "文字";

        Application.DoEvents();
    }


    MessageBox.Show("かんりょう");
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

テキストボックスへすべてのダンプ結果を書くのではなく、ページの管理を自分で行ったらいいと思います。具体的には、1行ごとの文字列の配列を作り、最初の1ページ分を表示します。1行送り、1行戻し、1ページ送り、1ページ戻しなどのボタンをつけて、押されるたびに、1ページ分のテキストボックスを更新します。
あとテキストエディタコントロールのようなものを使うのもいいかもしれません。
https://sgry.jp/pgarticles/cs_editor_component.html

Comment: ありがとうございました。…確かに、言われてみればその通りでした。設計に甘さがありました。もう一度設計から見直してみることにします。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。